# Error while using vars_prompt in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, centos7

I am using ansible 2.4 and running below main.yml file using command :

Command: ansible-playbook prompt.yml

main.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var1: a nice default
  vars_prompt:
    - name: test_var2
      prompt: "Enter a value"
      default: "{{ test_var1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=test_var2
```

file path: /etc/ansible/roles/prompt_file/tasks/main.yml

prompt.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
   - prompt_file
```

> I am getting below error after running this command:
>
> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled
>   module name, or incorrect module path.
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/roles/installedb_rpm/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3,
>   but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - hosts: localhost   ^ here
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/roles/installedb_rpm/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3,
>   but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - hosts: localhost   ^ here
>
> exception type:  exception:
>   no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module
>   name, or incorrect module path.
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/roles/installedb_rpm/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3,
>   but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - hosts: localhost   ^ here
>
>   What is the issue here?

Comment: Reason #2 in the dup-target.

Comment: Could you  please check this below. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Comment: I made below changes in main.yml:

---
-  name: Test vars
   vars_prompt:
    - name: test_var2
      prompt: "Enter a value"
   shell: echo {{test_var2}}

Now it is giving below WARNING:
[WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: vars_prompt

Comment: Can you guys please provide a sample working playbook that contains vars_prompt, so that i can test it on my end?

If not, please reopen this so that i can get more suggestions